# Not prompted to choose repository when adding new project to subversion

Tags: svn, repository, project, new-operator, ankhsvn

I've been using AnkhSVN with Visual Studio 2010 for a while and everything's been going on great, until today. I was able to create a new project and then I would be prompted to choose the repository. I would put the URL there and the project is online. Also I was able to open projects from repositories created by other with no difficulties.

But now, when I try to create a new project, tick the "Add to subversion" box, I don't get the dialog that asks me the repo URL. Instead, the project looks like already belongs to a subversion, but I don't know which and why.

How can I make Visual Studio ask me about the repository I want to use for my newly created project?

Note: I don't use Tortoise, nor SVN folders.

Answer (score 1):

Usually you only get into this situation when you are creating your project below an existing working copy.

Another case why this might happen is when you used an early AnkhSVN 2.3 (Based on Subversion 1.7) and try to add it below a Subversion 1.6 working copy. In that case you should Right Click -> Upgrade Working Copy. Newer 2.3 versions will warn you about this situation.